# Simplifying a One-Time Message Channel bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commando

I'm basically trying to make code into where it's user-friendly. Basically into a command. There are two commands but I'm only working on one at the moment. A one-time message channel. I'd like to make it where you can add a channel where if you speak once in the channel, the bot will give you a role that bans you from speaking in the channel.

The command is this

d!omca roleid channelid

then it will be added to the bot.

Here is the code I used.

```
    var commando = require('discord.js-commando');
var discord = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require("discord.js");

class omchannel extends commando.Command
{
    constructor(client)
    {
            super(client,{
                name: "omca",
                description: "Sets the one time message channel.",
                memberName: "omca",
                group: "channel",
                usage: "d!omca CHANNELID",
                accesableby: "Moderators",
                aliases: ["oneadd", "onemessagechanneladdition"]
        });
    }

async run(message, args)
{
    if(!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_CHANNELS", "MANAGE_ROLES"])) return message.channel.send("You don't have sufficent permissions to use this!")

    let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.id == args[0]) || message.mentions.roles.get(args[0])
    if(role) return message.channel.send("You did not specify a role ID. You can get a ID by doing backslash@ROLENAME (Make sure role is mentionable).")

    let channel = (channel => channel.id == args[1]) || message.channel.id(args[1])
    if(channel) return message.channel.send("You did not specify a channel ID. You can get one by going into Dev Mode, right click the channel in the sidebar, and press Copy ID.")

    if(message.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("I don't have sufficent permissions! Give me them!")

    if(message.channel.id == args[0]) {
    let bannedRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === args[1])
    message.member.addRole(bannedRole)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = omchannel;
```

I'm basically turning this code into something where the user can customize it.

```
doopliss.on('message', function(message) { {
if(message.channel.id == 'argument2') {
  let bannedRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'argument1');
      message.member.addRole(bannedRole);
  }
}})
```

Instead of using the role name, I want to use the role ID.

Expect : A command where you can customize what channel is a one-time message channel, and you get a role assigned after.

Happens : Discord Bot works, but doesn't work. (The bot functions fine but the wrong message is being said)

Comment: Which message is being said and what command do you have typed ?